# Django refresh page but dont redirect

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

On the page /home I created a login button in my navbar and when you click on it it will open a kind of a popup with changing display to block. But my problem is that I cant find out how the user could stay on the page when logging in with wrong data. At the moment it just returns me to the /home page and if I click again on the navbar button the login window opens with the "error" message but I want it to either redirect me to the /home page but the login popup is still opened or just don't redirect me anywhere.
**So I think I am just looking for a way that this message updates but you stay on the login popup**. Here is my

> part of the views.py:

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            # form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            # print(form.errors)
                # <process form cleaned data>
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                print(user, "has successfully logged in")
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/recipes/all')
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Password or username is incorrect")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/recipes/all')
```

And here is the part of my HTML file:

```
<div class="login-popup-box" id="login-popup-box">
            <div class="user-card-login">
              <div class="close-button-box">
                <button
                  class="close-button"
                  onclick="document.getElementById('login-popup-box').style.display='none'"
                  title="Close"
                >
                  <i class="fa fa-close close-button-icon"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <h1 class="login-title">Login</h1>
              {% for message in messages %}
    
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    
                            {{ message }}
    
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
    
              <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="input-group-username">
                  <div class="input-group-username-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  </div>
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Username..."
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-password">
                  <div class="input-group-password-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password..."
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="info-text">
                  <p>
                    Du hast keinen Account?
                    <a class="create-acc-link" onclick="viewChange('register')"
                      >Erstelle dir einfach einen</a
                    >
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <input class="login_btn" type="submit" value="Login" />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I really hope you can help me. Big Thank you!

PS: I also had the idea of passing something like a variable with the HTTP redirect so I can display the popup if this variable is true.

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform an AJAX request. Have you consider it?

Comment: I think this would be the solution but I can't test it out now so ill write later if it works Thanks!